# Difference between Click and Touch Listeners in Android

Tags: android

I have a bit of doubt. I am using an image button (e.g. Play icon in media player). I want to know which action Listener I am supposed to use, onClickListener or onTouchListener. What is the difference between those two actions and when should I use either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- **`onClickListener`** is used whenever a click event for any view is raised, say for example: click event for Button, ImageButton.
- **`onTouchListener`** is used whenever you want to implement Touch kind of functionality, say for example  if you want to get co-ordinates of screen where you touch exactly.

### Update:

Just check the official doc for both: [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

So from official doc, definition for both are:

- **onClickListner**: Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.
- **onTouchListener**: Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a touch event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before the touch event is given to the view.

Comment: That doesn't say much.. How do you define Click vs How you define touch.  A Nexus 4 for example has a screen and no mouse.

Answer (score 29):

The answer by @vishy1618 has the key insight of this thread (tried to leave this as a comment there, but too long).

Conceptually, onClick is just a 'wrapper' around a particular sequence of touch events - down, no drag, up. So comparing onTouch vs. onClick is just a low-level API (raw touch events) vs. a high-level API (a logical user 'click').

But, an important **compatibility issue**: in Android, onClick can also be fired by the KEYBOARD (or trackball, or whatever alternative input/hardware device is being used). But (afaict) there's no support for firing touch events via any other input device apart from the touch screen.

So, if you code your UI against touch events exclusively, you are implicitly *requiring a touchscreen*. Whereas if you stick to onClick, your app could theoretically work on a non-touch device.

Of course, all 'compliant' Android phones currently do have touch screens ... so this is effectively moot. But if you want your app to work on non-phone hardware, this might be worth considering.

There is some good discussion here:

[How to determine if an Android device has a touchscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454650/are-there-any-android-devices-without-touch-screen)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-beginners/cjOVcn0sqLg

Comment: +1 this is the only answer that actually stated the difference between a click and a touch, for a device with no mouse..

Comment: Even 15 years ago VB gave options like onMouseDown and onMouseUp. It seems that onClick requires a down and an up. and Android doesn't offer anything for specifically just the 'up'..

Answer (score 8):

The onClickListener is a number of events that are triggered using either the keyboard or the touchscreen. They are performed on a specific view, and the entire view receives the event. In contrast, the onTouchListener is used only for touchscreen events, and they cannot be triggered through the keyboard or any other inputs. They typically also receive the corresponding touch information like the x, y corrdinates, etc.

I think the onClickListener would be appropriate for your application, if you are not using more complex inputs, like gestures, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This question I also got in mind that should use click or touch listener.

Then I have my understandings like this,

When I need any `View(Button/Image/etc) to make clickable` that means user *just don't touch that part of screen but delebrately try to Touch* on that part of screen so the next action gets called I `use onClickListener` , Also another thing is like suppose working with Button we can *make it Clickable True/False* as per requirement dynamically,Hence in this situations the OnClickListener is preffered.

```
new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
```

While developing screens `where the simple Touch of User is to be taken as action` like more in Games or Working with Images that you want to capture that where user has touched and also you need `to find the Motion Events up/down/left/righ`t of the Touch I preffer to *`use onTouchListener`.*

```
new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        };
```

And
In your case *I suggest to use the onClickListener*

Answer (score 0):

Extra information for anyone viewing this thread in the future:

When you set the FocusableInTouchMode property for the view to "True" onClick will not fire until the second click/touch on the view. I assume the OS treats the first touch as gaining focus only. OnTouch however, fires on the first touch.

When FocusableInTouchMode = "False" both will fire on the first touch.