# Android OnClick and onTouch : Which one is better?

Tags: android, listener, ontouchlistener, onclicklistener

I am developing a android application, in which we have standard login registration pages.

I like to ask about onClick listener and onTouch listener, which action listener is better for implementing actions on buttons. And there are any effects if I used any of listener?

Comment: Definitely onClickListener is what I prefer when you want to keep things simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Click and Touch Listeners in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046845/difference-between-click-and-touch-listeners-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `onClick` for regular button clicks.

`onTouch` is used for gesture detection (swiping, tapping, double-tapping, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think onTouch will call when you touch if u not removed your finger also.

and onClick will call once you click and remove finger